# How to show 'JAlert' popup for multiple times?

Tags: jquery, alert

I know I could call `alert('Warning1');alert('Warning2');`
and it will show 2 alerts. But, when I use JAlert plugin referred in [JAlert Page](http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin/#creating) I can't show multiple alert messages. Does any of you guys ever worked with this plugin and solved same problem?

Comment: You linked to the wrong plugin... it is about a context menu.

Comment: http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/projects/js/jquery/alerts/demo/

Comment: Do you want to show 2 alerts at the same time? or one after another?

Comment: Yes it can, if you mean [this](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/projects/js/jquery/alerts/demo/jquery.alerts.js) plugin - post your code and we'll see what went wrong.

Comment: Yes, I want to show 2 alert one after another. There is nothing fancy going on with the code. All I want to do is call jAlert('Message 1', 'Warning'); and jAlert('Message 2', 'Warning'); in same time, so user could see these warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right- so i made a sample HTML and tested this thing out

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<head>
<!-- Dependencies -->
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Core files -->
<script src="jquery.alerts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready( function() {

          jAlert('This is a custom alert box', 'Alert Dialog', doAlert()  );

          function doAlert() {
              alert('CallBack')
          }

        });
</script> 

</head>

<body>
</body>
```

So based on the docuemntation from the website

> Usage
>   This plugin utilizes the $.alerts namespace, but there are three built-in shortcut functions >that make implementation easier:
>
> jAlert(message, [title, callback])

Ok now this is the logic of the jQuery

1. document ready starts
2. jAlert shows a custom box and by defination should do the callback doAlert()
3. As soon as the first jAlert clsoes it will do the callback and open another instance of jALert

What actually happens

1. the **function doAlert** fires before the actual jAlert that is calling the callback
2. the first jAlert fires OK! but does  not show up because there is already a jAlert isntance and jsut ignores whatever happens

In conclusion

This plugin cannot handle multiple calls internally and the callback is wrong! because it is not calling back but calling a function before it calls its self or waits for the inital jAlert to be accepted

Solution

1. Find another plugin
2. Create an internal jScript queue system. somehow based on how terribly this plugin works

Why Does alert(); work then??!?!?!?!?

Because when you call `alert();`  the code execution STOPS and waits until you press OK and continues the code.

So i am sorry to say but this plugin is not functioning properly and i suggest you find another one maybe.

Comment: i will try and make some code to do what you need. But for now I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks. Gotta find another plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it like this:
in the jquery.alerts.js, just before the comment for public functions, I have inserted this:

```
    raiseNextDialog: function() {
        $.alerts.callIsActive = false;
        if ($.alerts.waitingCalls.length>0) {
            var params = $.alerts.waitingCalls.shift();
            $.alerts._show(params[0], params[1], params[2], params[3], params[4]);
        }
    },
    dialogShallWait: function (title, msg, value, type, callback) {
        if ($.alerts.callIsActive) {
            $.alerts.waitingCalls.push([title, msg, value, type, callback]);
            return true; // can't show now
        } else {
            $.alerts.callIsActive = true;
            return false;
        }
    },
```

The idea is that if  a previous dialog is still open, we push the call into array, to be used when the dialog is closed.

Now we still need to add a line to the beginning of the _show() function:

```
if ( $.alerts.dialogShallWait(title, msg, value, type, callback) ) return;
```

And for the five .click() handlers we need to add this line after calling the callback:

```
$.alerts.raiseNextDialog();
```

That's all!

I wanted to update the creator but there was no way to leave a comment in his site...
And I am using the wonderful version demonstrated [here](http://beckelman.net/Demos/jQueryAlertDialogs/Default.aspx) which uses standard themes. Just great!

Comment: I've also faced a same issue, my customer was requesting an alert box for reminding session time, and then another alert box for expired session after 5 minutes after that. A developer has used jAlert for all alert boxes so I were using it too. I tried but your code hasn't worked, I think there was something wrong with raiseNextDialog() method, as the second alert was only appeared in a short time and closed itself immediately. To save time, I went with a simple solution to solve my case that by using some flags :). Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer was partially correct but failed to define the array that holds the multiple alerts ($.alerts.waitingCalls). The code below replaces the entire jquery.alerts.js (the entire package is available at: http://code.google.com/p/jalert-plus/downloads/list )

```
// jQuery Alert Dialogs Plugin
//
// Version 1.1 (extended)
//
// Cory S.N. LaViska
// A Beautiful Site (http://abeautifulsite.net/)
// 14 May 2009
//
// Mike Walters
// 27 December 2011
// http://code.google.com/p/jalert-plus/downloads/list
//
// Visit http://abeautifulsite.net/notebook/87 for more information
//
// Usage:
//      jAlert( message, [title, callback] )
//      jConfirm( message, [title, callback] )
//      jPrompt( message, [value, title, callback] )
// 
// History:
//
//      1.00 - Released (29 December 2008)
//
//      1.01 - Fixed bug where unbinding would destroy all resize events
//
//      DECEMBER 2011 - added ability to popup multiple alerts (mike walters)
//
// License:
// 
// This plugin is dual-licensed under the GNU General Public License and the MIT License and
// is copyright 2008 A Beautiful Site, LLC. 
//



(function($) {

    $.alerts = {

        // These properties can be read/written by accessing $.alerts.propertyName from your scripts at any time

        verticalOffset: -75,                // vertical offset of the dialog from center screen, in pixels
        horizontalOffset: 0,                // horizontal offset of the dialog from center screen, in pixels/
        repositionOnResize: true,           // re-centers the dialog on window resize
        overlayOpacity: .01,                // transparency level of overlay
        overlayColor: '#FFF',               // base color of overlay
        draggable: true,                    // make the dialogs draggable (requires UI Draggables plugin)
        okButton: '&nbsp;OK&nbsp;',         // text for the OK button
        cancelButton: '&nbsp;Cancel&nbsp;', // text for the Cancel button
        dialogClass: null,                  // if specified, this class will be applied to all dialogs

        waitingCalls: new Array(),

        raiseNextDialog: function() {
            $.alerts.callIsActive = false;
            if ($.alerts.waitingCalls.length>0) {
                var params = $.alerts.waitingCalls.shift();
                $.alerts._show(params[0], params[1], params[2], params[3], params[4]);
            }
        },

        dialogShallWait: function (title, msg, value, type, callback) {
            if ($.alerts.callIsActive) {

                $.alerts.waitingCalls.push([title, msg, value, type, callback]);
                return true; // can't show now
            } else {
                $.alerts.callIsActive = true;
                return false;
            }
        },


        // Public methods

        alert: function(message, title, callback) {
            if( title == null ) title = 'Alert';
            $.alerts._show(title, message, null, 'alert', function(result) {
                if( callback ) callback(result);
            });
        },

        confirm: function(message, title, callback) {
            if( title == null ) title = 'Confirm';
            $.alerts._show(title, message, null, 'confirm', function(result) {
                if( callback ) callback(result);
            });
        },

        prompt: function(message, value, title, callback) {
            if( title == null ) title = 'Prompt';
            $.alerts._show(title, message, value, 'prompt', function(result) {
                if( callback ) callback(result);
            });
        },

        // Private methods

        _show: function(title, msg, value, type, callback) {


        if ( $.alerts.dialogShallWait(title, msg, value, type, callback) ) return;

            $.alerts._hide();
            $.alerts._overlay('show');

            $("BODY").append(
              '<div id="popup_container">' +
                '<h1 id="popup_title"></h1>' +
                '<div id="popup_content">' +
                  '<div id="popup_message"></div>' +
                '</div>' +
              '</div>');

            if( $.alerts.dialogClass ) $("#popup_container").addClass($.alerts.dialogClass);

            // IE6 Fix
            var pos = ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) <= 6 ) ? 'absolute' : 'fixed'; 

            $("#popup_container").css({
                position: pos,
                zIndex: 99999,
                padding: 0,
                margin: 0
            });

            $("#popup_title").text(title);
            $("#popup_content").addClass(type);
            $("#popup_message").text(msg);
            $("#popup_message").html( $("#popup_message").text().replace(/\n/g, '<br />') );

            $("#popup_container").css({
                minWidth: $("#popup_container").outerWidth(),
                maxWidth: $("#popup_container").outerWidth()
            });

            $.alerts._reposition();
            $.alerts._maintainPosition(true);

            switch( type ) {
                case 'alert':
                    $("#popup_message").after('<div id="popup_panel"><input type="button" value="' + $.alerts.okButton + '" id="popup_ok" /></div>');

                    $("#popup_ok").click( function() {
                        $.alerts._hide();
                        callback(true);
                        $.alerts.raiseNextDialog();
                    });
                    $("#popup_ok").focus().keypress( function(e) {
                        if( e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 27 ) $("#popup_ok").trigger('click');
                    });
                break;
                case 'confirm':
                    $("#popup_message").after('<div id="popup_panel"><input type="button" value="' + $.alerts.okButton + '" id="popup_ok" /> <input type="button" value="' + $.alerts.cancelButton + '" id="popup_cancel" /></div>');
                    $("#popup_ok").click( function() {
                        $.alerts._hide();
                        if( callback ) callback(true);
                        $.alerts.raiseNextDialog();
                    });
                    $("#popup_cancel").click( function() {
                        $.alerts._hide();
                        if( callback ) callback(false);
                        $.alerts.raiseNextDialog();
                    });
                    $("#popup_ok").focus();
                    $("#popup_ok, #popup_cancel").keypress( function(e) {
                        if( e.keyCode == 13 ) $("#popup_ok").trigger('click');
                        if( e.keyCode == 27 ) $("#popup_cancel").trigger('click');
                    });
                break;
                case 'prompt':
                    $("#popup_message").append('<br /><input type="text" size="30" id="popup_prompt" />').after('<div id="popup_panel"><input type="button" value="' + $.alerts.okButton + '" id="popup_ok" /> <input type="button" value="' + $.alerts.cancelButton + '" id="popup_cancel" /></div>');
                    $("#popup_prompt").width( $("#popup_message").width() );
                    $("#popup_ok").click( function() {
                        var val = $("#popup_prompt").val();
                        $.alerts._hide();
                        if( callback ) callback( val );
                        $.alerts.raiseNextDialog();
                    });
                    $("#popup_cancel").click( function() {
                        $.alerts._hide();
                        if( callback ) callback( null );
                        $.alerts.raiseNextDialog();
                    });
                    $("#popup_prompt, #popup_ok, #popup_cancel").keypress( function(e) {
                        if( e.keyCode == 13 ) $("#popup_ok").trigger('click');
                        if( e.keyCode == 27 ) $("#popup_cancel").trigger('click');
                    });
                    if( value ) $("#popup_prompt").val(value);
                    $("#popup_prompt").focus().select();
                break;
            }

            // Make draggable
            if( $.alerts.draggable ) {
                try {
                    $("#popup_container").draggable({ handle: $("#popup_title") });
                    $("#popup_title").css({ cursor: 'move' });
                } catch(e) { /* requires jQuery UI draggables */ }
            }
        },

        _hide: function() {
            $("#popup_container").remove();
            $.alerts._overlay('hide');
            $.alerts._maintainPosition(false);
        },

        _overlay: function(status) {
            switch( status ) {
                case 'show':
                    $.alerts._overlay('hide');
                    $("BODY").append('<div id="popup_overlay"></div>');
                    $("#popup_overlay").css({
                        position: 'absolute',
                        zIndex: 99998,
                        top: '0px',
                        left: '0px',
                        width: '100%',
                        height: $(document).height(),
                        background: $.alerts.overlayColor,
                        opacity: $.alerts.overlayOpacity
                    });
                break;
                case 'hide':
                    $("#popup_overlay").remove();
                break;
            }
        },

        _reposition: function() {
            var top = (($(window).height() / 2) - ($("#popup_container").outerHeight() / 2)) + $.alerts.verticalOffset;
            var left = (($(window).width() / 2) - ($("#popup_container").outerWidth() / 2)) + $.alerts.horizontalOffset;
            if( top < 0 ) top = 0;
            if( left < 0 ) left = 0;

            // IE6 fix
            if( $.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) <= 6 ) top = top + $(window).scrollTop();

            $("#popup_container").css({
                top: top + 'px',
                left: left + 'px'
            });
            $("#popup_overlay").height( $(document).height() );
        },

        _maintainPosition: function(status) {
            if( $.alerts.repositionOnResize ) {
                switch(status) {
                    case true:
                        $(window).bind('resize', $.alerts._reposition);
                    break;
                    case false:
                        $(window).unbind('resize', $.alerts._reposition);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    // Shortuct functions
    jAlert = function(message, title, callback) {
        $.alerts.alert(message, title, callback);
    }

    jConfirm = function(message, title, callback) {
        $.alerts.confirm(message, title, callback);
    };

    jPrompt = function(message, value, title, callback) {
        $.alerts.prompt(message, value, title, callback);
    };

})(jQuery);
```